# Chrome Extension for altering "search on page"-behavior. Is this possible to make?

Tags: google-chrome, search, interface, module

**Hi there chrome pros!**

I have an idea for a chrome extension: To be able to follow a link that has been found by searching on the page. *The general idea is this:* You have a webpage of a bunch of links. You don't want to visually scan all of them, so you hit Ctrl+f and searches for the link you want. Now instead of using your mouse to click the link, lastly you hit, say, Ctrl+Enter to follow the link.

Now I've been looking over the Chrome extensions API but I can't seem to find a handhold for starting development of the extension. *So my question is this* - is it possible for an extension to alter the behaviour of the chrome application itself and in that case, where should I be looking in the API, tutorials or any other resource that can get me started.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

Comment: I don't think it's possible other than by injecting code into Chrome's process using an NPAPI plugin, which is extremely messy (like [Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn)) or you can try overriding Ctrl+F like Google Docs does, but for all pages.

Comment: but don't worry, [you're not the first person to think of that](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150#c9).

Comment: agh, actually in that case [it's already implemented](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-type-ahead/), sorry for over-commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, sorry for spamming three comments, but I just realized that it actually does work. (Chrome 18.0.1025.162 in Ubuntu)

Again, if you want to modify the core behavior for another reason you'd need to inject code into the Chrome process which isn't pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I guess altering the native search-functionality of  chrome seems a little hairy. I'll do some research on the overriding Ctrl+F method. Thanks for the suggestion too!

Comment: Um, I meant the feature you suggested it actually implemented. Try using Ctrl+F on a link and press Ctrl+Enter - tada!